# Can I increment 2 variables by same value at a time in single line of code in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started learning python recently. This is my python3 code. if condition satisfies I need to increment both variables value by one. How can I do so in one line, This code works fine. Can I make this code short and sweet in one line? Thanks in advance.

```
//This code works fine
if(letters[index] == letters[index+1]):
    count += 1
    index += 1
```

Is it possible to do this in 1 line. I mean something like this
`[count,index]+=1`(this doesn't work)

Comment: You can, but it won't be an improvement.

Comment: Yes. I thought to make code short. But I realized from the answers that it cannot be made short.

Comment: count, index = letters[index] == letters[index+1] and (count+1, index+1) or (count, index)

Answer (score 2):

you could do

```
if(letters[index] == letters[index+1]):
    count,index=count+1,index+1
```

or

```
if(letters[index] == letters[index+1]):
    count+=1;index+=1
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and I realized code cannot be made short.

Answer (score 2):

A bit more work but

```
def increment(x):
    return x + 1
```

And then

```
 a, b, c = map(increment,[a, b, c])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and I realized code cannot be made short.

Answer (score 2):

**Just for fun** - entirely overkill, but you can do:

```py
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.index = 0
    
    # behaviour for += operator
    def __iadd__(self, inc: int):
        assert isinstance(inc, int)
        self.count += inc
        self.index += inc
        return self
```

and use it as:

```py
c = C()
c += 1
# c.count and c.index are both 1
c += 10
# c.count and c.index are both 11
```

Comment: ha ha.. I thought to make code short and this is a straight opposite of my expectation. And in your code, the first part is it an inbuilt function?

Comment: Yes, in [`__iadd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=iadd#object.__iadd__) you implement the operator `+=` for your class.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
count, index = (count+1,index+1) if letters[index] == letters[index+1] else (count,index)
```

Comment: Wow. This is an interesting answer and this code works. But when I embed this code inside my full code(my full code is a nested if statement) that throws an error. May be problem with indentation.

Comment: Although it is indeed a "one-liner", this statement is highly repetitive and increases the visual complexity. Do not complicate things just to reduce the number of lines.